# Error al compilar app de ionic con FCM

Tags: angular, ionic, fcm

no puedo compilar una app de ionic 4 con FCM en Android, adjunto los errores dados:

D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
35 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 31 up-to-date
C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\LifeventApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

LLEVO DÍAS TRATANDO DE RESOLVER ESTO, POR FAVOR NECESITO UNA SUGERENCIA.

Comment: Lo conseguiste tengo el mismo problema===?=??

Comment: Si, ejecuta estos 2 comandos: "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx"
"cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter". Luego compila tu proyecto y se ejecuta sin problemas.